# Функция аля Split

Tags: java, массивы, функции, циклы, split

Напишите функцию, которая принимает строку и возвращает массив слов.

Под словом подразумеваются множество символов отличных от пробела. Между словами может стоять больше одного пробела.

Максимальная длина строки 10^6 символов.
Сигнатура функции

**Название функции:** split.

**Параметры:** String s.

**Возвращаемый тип:** String[].

**Пример:**

**Входные данные:**

> s = "Any TexSt";

**Выходные данные:**

> result = [ "Any", "TexSt" ];

```
public static String[] split(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length - 1; i++) {
        if (i == 0 && (int) c[i] <= 127 && (int) c[i] != 32 || (int) c[i] == 32 && (int) c[i + 1] <= 127 && (int) c[i + 1] != 32) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    String temp = "";
    int k = 0;
    String[] result = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if ((int) c[i] != 32) {
            result[k] = temp;
            temp = temp + c[i];
            result[k] = temp;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Здравствуйте.Выше описаны условия задачи.Создать некое подобие функции сплит.Застрял на том моменте,что не могу получить результат в n-количестве слов.Экспериментировал очень много,дебажил.
На платформе очень много тестов.
например входные данные могут быть и такими :

```
" t        test           tes   t"
```

Вот ,тот код ,каким я решил на платформе.Его я нашел (естественно).

```
public static String[] split(String s) {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder currentWord = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character letter : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (letter.equals(' ')) {
            if (currentWord.length() > 0) {
                words.add(currentWord.toString());
                currentWord = new StringBuilder();
            }
        } else {
            currentWord.append(letter);
        }
    }
    if (currentWord.length() > 0) {
        words.add(currentWord.toString());
    }
    String[] wordsArr = words.toArray(String[]::new);
    return  wordsArr;
}
```

Comment: Ах,да.Если кто-то захочет минуснуть,пожалуйста,я не против.Я задачу решил.Решил конечно по другому,это не совсем правильно с моей стороны.Но я уже просто отчаялся.Я просто хочу понять,как её сделать стандартными средствами.

Comment: Стандартными средствами - это метод split вызвать? Какие проблемы с этим?

Comment: Вы говорите, что решили задачу, а вы свой код запускали? Я вот вижу, что ваш код не решает задачу.

Comment: Сделал правку в теме.Написал код,которым я решил.
Но мне хочется ,что бы кто-то подсказал,что мне нужно изменить в моём коде,что бы заработало так,как надо.

Comment: В вашем решении 2 цикла и оба неправильные. В первом у вас какая то свистопляска с числами, которой быть не должно. Во втором цикле вы индекс К не увеличиваете никогда плюс вы конкатенируете строки, что является очень медленной операцией. Если править ваш код, то это будет выглядеть как удаление ваших циклов и заменой конкатенации на string builder, и в результате получится что то похожее на второй вариант. То есть по сути вы просите выкинуть ваш код и сказать, что второй вариант неплох.

Comment: Окей.Если Вам не трудно и у Вас есть на это время,предложите свой вариант кода.Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как альтернативный пример. Проматываем все пробелы, потом забираем слово и так по кругу.

```
public static String[] split(String s) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int ind = 0;

    while (ind < s.length())
    {
        while (ind < s.length() && s.charAt(ind) == ' ') ind++;
        int start = ind;
        while (ind < s.length() && s.charAt(ind) != ' ') ind++;
        if (start != ind)
            result.add(s.substring(start, ind));
    }

    return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь)

Comment: на здоровье! Если помогло, то галочка слева от ответа.